# ModuleNotFoundError in Spyder using vgg16

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

When I write the python code in Spyder

```
from vgg16 import VGG16

it says module not found error: Module name 'vgg16'
```

Comment: sorry about the "trivial" answer, but did you already installed Keras on your env? It is working correctly? 
I see this issue coming from a missing package, nothing related to Spyder specifically, as far as I can read here.

Comment: yes Keras is installed and working fine